# how do i get rid of this "ridge" completely, without really changing the shape of the mesh?

Tags: modeling, mirror-modifier, clipping

[image]

how do i get rid of this "ridge" completely, without really changing the shape of the mesh?

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Make sure there isn't an internal face down the centre of the mirror modifier.